# Python equivalent for manipulating variable in R summarise

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am looking for an equivalent python command for this R command.

```
DF%>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(
    Var1 = mean(Option[Var_A== 1] == Option[Var_B== 1]))
```

Here is an extraction of my DF.
Group = Grouping Variable
2 different Variables coded binary (Var_A and Var_B)

Option = the alternative in this set

```py
DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Group': {('No_1', 1): 'Group_A',
  ('No_1', 2): 'Group_A',
  ('No_1', 3): 'Group_A',
  ('No_1', 4): 'Group_A',
  ('No_1', 5): 'Group_A',
  ('No_1', 6): 'Group_A',
  ('No_1', 7): 'Group_A',
  ('No_1', 8): 'Group_A',
  ('No_24', 1): 'Group_B',
  ('No_24', 2): 'Group_B',
  ('No_24', 3): 'Group_B',
  ('No_24', 4): 'Group_B',
  ('No_24', 5): 'Group_B',
  ('No_24', 6): 'Group_B',
  ('No_24', 7): 'Group_B',
  ('No_24', 8): 'Group_B'},
 'Var_A': {('No_1', 1): 0,
  ('No_1', 2): 0,
  ('No_1', 3): 0,
  ('No_1', 4): 1,
  ('No_1', 5): 0,
  ('No_1', 6): 0,
  ('No_1', 7): 0,
  ('No_1', 8): 0,
  ('No_24', 1): 0,
  ('No_24', 2): 0,
  ('No_24', 3): 0,
  ('No_24', 4): 1,
  ('No_24', 5): 0,
  ('No_24', 6): 0,
  ('No_24', 7): 0,
  ('No_24', 8): 0},
 'Var_B': {('No_1', 1): 0,
  ('No_1', 2): 0,
  ('No_1', 3): 0,
  ('No_1', 4): 1,
  ('No_1', 5): 0,
  ('No_1', 6): 0,
  ('No_1', 7): 0,
  ('No_1', 8): 0,
  ('No_24', 1): 0,
  ('No_24', 2): 0,
  ('No_24', 3): 0,
  ('No_24', 4): 1,
  ('No_24', 5): 0,
  ('No_24', 6): 0,
  ('No_24', 7): 0,
  ('No_24', 8): 0},
 'Option': {('No_1', 1): 1,
  ('No_1', 2): 2,
  ('No_1', 3): 3,
  ('No_1', 4): 4,
  ('No_1', 5): 5,
  ('No_1', 6): 6,
  ('No_1', 7): 7,
  ('No_1', 8): 8,
  ('No_24', 1): 1,
  ('No_24', 2): 2,
  ('No_24', 3): 3,
  ('No_24', 4): 4,
  ('No_24', 5): 5,
  ('No_24', 6): 6,
  ('No_24', 7): 7,
  ('No_24', 8): 8}})
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: In this case it would be 1 for both, since Var_A and Var_B are 1 in the same row. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you check `df.assign(Var1=df['Var_A'] == df['Var_B']).groupby('Group')['Var1'].mean()`? But I don't understand the Option column

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working, so basically they have to be summarised first. If the value of Option for Var_A== 1 is the same as the value of Option for Var_B then it is counted as correct otherwise as false. So basically it first needs to be summarized to either correct or false and then afterwards mean needs to be built. Hope this helps.

Comment: `Option[Var_A== 1] == alt[Var_B== 1]` can throw error if `sum(Var_A == 1) != sum(Var_B==1)`. What would happen in that case ? Also what is `alt` ?

Comment: Sorry, alt is Option, adapted it. Sum(Var_A==1) == sum(Var_B==1) is true. Thanks a lot